# How to authorize to download PDF document from content got from google-documents list-api

Tags: coldfusion, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have list of google docs which i got by authorizing myself with below code:

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin" method="post" result="result" charset="utf-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Email" value="abc@gmail.com">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Passwd" value="xyz">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="service" value="writely">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="source" value="abc-xyz-2010">
    </cfhttp>
```

Now I am able to download word documents and PPT by the help of content.xmlAttribute from the xml file having all documents.
But I am not able to download PDF files. Error message I am getting is "Authorization require error 401".I checked documentation it say that:
It is also not possible to manually contruct the download URL for these types of files. Instead, send an authenticated HTTP GET to the entry's  src link:

```
<content type="text/html" src="https://doc-04-20-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/m7an0emtau/WJm.../YzI2Y2ExYWVm?h=16655626&e=download&gd=true"/>
```

Can someone please tell me how to pass authorization information and get the PDF download link working.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace *method="post"* with *method="get"* ?